# PowerApp convert value datetime

Tags: powerapps

My excel data is 8/1/2022  7:55:06 AM and i have change format to time (locale US). In PowerApps i'm using Text(DateAdd(ThisItem.Checkin,TimeZoneOffset(),Minutes),ShortTime)
For file <5000 rows is correct format 7:55:06 AM
But with excel file over 5000 rows it show value 44776.4357060
How can i convert 44776.4357060 to time format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel date/time numbers are based on the number of days since its epoch, and the time component is the fractional part. To convert that value into a time format, you can use the Time function and pass the number of milliseconds that the fraction represents:

```
Time(0, 0, 0, 0.4357060 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
```

Comment: how can i get 0.4357060? I try use split but not yet extract correct.

Comment: i can do it, thank you so much.

Comment: You can do something like `ThisItem.Checkin - Int(ThisItem.Checkin)` to get the fractional part of a number